# Filtering a WP Query result

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I have several custom type posts which I already filtered using WP Query.

From that list, I am trying to filter the posts that have a specific Custom Field value.

I tried using a meta_query, but the problem is that the select value does not exist yet. It only exists once the query has finished. I already have the select value stored in a variable.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array(
        'one',
        'two',
        'three'
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'owner',
            //'value' => $currentSignedUser,
            //'value' => 'Owner'
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo '<h5>List of owned stuff: </h5><br />';

while($query->have_posts()) :
    $query->the_post();
    ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <br />
    <?php
    $owner_select = get_field('owner');

    if ($owner_select) {
        echo 'Owner: ' . $owner_select[display_name];
    } else{
        echo '<p style="color:darkred"><strong>No associated owner for this item.</strong></p>' ;
    }
    ?> </p>
    <?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

How can I filter the first query results with another query? Would this be the correct way or is it another method?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more context as your question is a little confusing, the title implies something involving `pre_get_posts`, but it sounds like you want to take the results of your query and find a subset of them at a later time, but if I take your question literally it doesn't say that

Comment: I updated your code to be more readable by using coding standards and consistent indenting, but your loop should have an `if ( $query->have_posts() )` check, should call `wp_reset_postdata` not `wp_reset_query` ( reset query is only to be used when cleaning up after a `query_posts` call ), and it should only call `wp_reset_postdata` if there are posts to cleanup ( aka if `$query->the_post()` was called )

Comment: I am not very well versed on Wordpress lingo, but I guess that's exactly what I want to do: filter a subset of my query results using a meta_query that filters with the value of a custom field selector.

Comment: BTW, I was following this tutorial: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/mastering-wp-query. Where can I read more about the changes you suggested, @TomJNowell? Thanks.

Comment: It's rare that people would take a WP_Query object, and then perform additional querying on stuff that's already been queried. Instead take the data/results it retrieved and create a second query. The other changes I suggested are all self explanatory, ask a question on the site if you need more detail

Comment: My last question is how should I search google for querying results from a previous query? I get the concept perfecty but I am not a PHP expert, so I still need guidance. I've been searching for "query within a query", "filtering query results", and so on.

Thanks again.

Comment: I'd advise you create a second query that contains all the parameters from the first, but with your extra check. Taking you literally there's no way to do this, WP_Query was built to grab posts from the database and support a post loop. It isn't a generic container you can perform array operations on

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem re-reading [ACF's custom fields documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/).

Instead of meta_query, I should've used meta_key.

The correct argument for a custom field is:

```
// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'event',
    'meta_key'      => 'location',
    'meta_value'    => 'Melbourne'
);
```